# Drawing "beautiful spheres" in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I found some ready-made code to draw spheres and lines on them in [this paper](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb33-1/tb103wolcott.pdf), which refers to [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/map-projections/).

Bottom line is that I do not get the presented result using MiKTeX on 64-bit Windows 7, using either the LaTeX->dvi->ps->pdf chain or direct PDFLaTeX.

These are the results of the example code in the second link on my system:

[image]

[image]

Everything seems fine except the latitude and longitude lines. How can I solve this?

Comment: Please narrow down your problem. Insert one single example in your post and show the output of just this example. Then explain where you are having the error, what the log is saying (if there is something special), and what you expect it to look like. In the current state, I would have to open two external links (which I won't), search the code to play around with, and search your posted images for the possible error you are seeing.

Comment: I have the same problem with TeXLive 2014 in Fedora Linux.